# R loop: Downloading multiple csv files with varying dates in the url

Tags: r, loops, date, export-to-csv

I wanted to download the weather data for all the days in a month from the following website:

```
https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KSEA/2013/1/8/DailyHistory.html?format=1
```

I realized that this can be done just by changing the dates in the above weblink. For example for 9th January the link will be

```
...KSEA/2013/1/9/DailyHistory.html?format=1
```

So, when I'm downloading this data individually, I'm able to get the csv files but when I tried writing a `for` loop for the entire month it is just not working. Following is the code I used for individual file download:

```
download.file(url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KSEA/2013/1/8/DailyHistory.html?MR=1&format=1',
              destfile = "/Users/ABCD/Desktop/weather.csv")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I'm having a problem with X, here is my code for Y."  Can you please [edit] your question to include the for loop that isn't working?

Comment: Have you looked into the `weatherData` package. That might make things a little easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be surprised that putting "2013/01/08" instead of "2013/1/8" in the url also works. This make things easier, as we can make use of "Date" object in R.

The following function will download all data from a starting date (say "2013/01/01") to an end date (say "2013/02/28"). You can customize your start date and end date. In the end, the downloaded file will be, for example, "/Users/ABCD/Desktop/weather/2013-01-01.csv". (You need to create the directory "/Users/ABCD/Desktop/weather") first.

```
mydownload <- function (start_date, end_date) {
  start_date <- as.Date(start_date)  ## convert to Date object
  end_date <- as.Date(end_date)  ## convert to Date object
  dates <- as.Date("1970/01/01") + (start_date : end_date)  ## date sequence
  ## a loop to download data
  for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
    string_date <- as.character(dates[i])
    myfile <- paste0("/Users/ABCD/Desktop/weather/", string_date, ".csv")
    string_date <- gsub("-", "/", string_date)  ## replace "-" with "/"
    myurl <- paste("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KSEA", string_date, "DailyHistory.html?MR=1&format=1", sep = "/")
    download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE)
    }
  }

mydownload("2013/01/01", "2013/02/28")
```

---

**Comments:**

1. Initially I used

   ```
   for (mydate in dates) {
     string_date <- as.character(mydate)
   ```

   but the answer is not right. Somehow `mydate` has been coerced into integer. In the end I have to do

   ```
   for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
     string_date <- as.character(dates[i])
   ```
2. Using a `for` loop is decent here. No need to do `lapply` or similar, because `download.file()` takes considerable time so loop overhead is insignificant.

Comment: Thanks for your help but try opening the files generated using the above code, it has copied the html code for the weblink inside the csv file and not the actual text of the link. So, the loop did work here but the files generated do not have the information I'm looking for. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the date format!